# Streaming Web cam real-time buffer [Toshiba Webcam] [video input] too full or near too full

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

I am trying to stream my webcam with audio from microphone of laptop(OS: windows 7 ) to nginx server (Compiled with rtmp module in CentOS 6.6 final) in same local network.
 From my laptop, I execute this command in CMD:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Toshiba Webcam" -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Périphérique High D" -vf scale=1280:720 -vcodec libx264 -r 60.97 -acodec libvo_aacenc -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 128 -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -f flv "rtmp://172.16.40.162/dash/test"
```

But I got this message:
[image]

And I had about retard delay  of 23 second when I open http://localhost:8080 ( I made the indx.html file of nginx with JWPlayer)

So my questions are:

How can I improve the ffmpeg cmd to avoid the errors of buffer too full?

How eliminate or reduce the latency ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the audio bitrate from `-ab 128` (**bits!**) to `-ab 128k`.

See if this fixes the errors. If not then try increasing the real-time buffer size using `-rtbufsize integer (input)`.

The latency parameters look OK. You can reduce the buffer size (3 seconds by default) on JWPlayer using [bufferlength](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430358-using-rtmp-streaming). Fix your errors first though.